# Export Feature with attribute to dxf

Tags: qgis, dxf

I'm trying to export features with at least one attribute to dxf, is that possible? E.g. I need the name or layer name of the feature in the CAD application.

Comment: I used to create linetypes with specific names and apply the attribute value to that. another method is use a specific color. Or apply an attrbute to layer. You would probably have to have Map3d to accomplish this. But DXF is a simplified exchange format. There are not a lot of options unless you are a proficient programmer. http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf  or https://www.google.com/search?q=dxf+file+specifications